Crash on the TextView in the ForEach wrapped to the ScrollView and programmatically set FocusState
I have a crash in my apps(6 different apps) on the TextField.
I have a code for adding players with TextField in the ForEach and wrapped to ScrollView
My code:
@StateObject var viewState: PlayerViewState
        
        @FocusState var focusItemId: UUID?
        
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                ZStack {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        HStack {
                            Button {
                                viewState.didTapBackButton()
                            } label: {
                                Text(L10n.Localizable.BackButton.title)
                                    .font(.HelveticaNeue(size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(Asset.accentColor.swiftUIColor)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(L10n.Localizable.Players.title.uppercased())
                                .font(.HelveticaNeueMedium(size: 65))
                                .foregroundColor(Asset.textForegroundColor.swiftUIColor)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 12))
                            
                        }.padding(.bottom, 42)
                        ZStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text(L10n.Localizable.Players.Text.enterNameClickOnText)
                                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                                    .foregroundColor(Asset.textForegroundColor.swiftUIColor)
                                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                                    .fixedSize()
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 180)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 200)
                                    .padding(.leading, 8)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            ScrollViewReader { value in
                                ScrollView {
                                    VStack {
                                        ForEach($viewState.players) { player in
                                            VStack {
                                                TextField(L10n.Localizable.Players.Text.enterName, text: player.name)
                                                    .focused($focusItemId, equals: player.id)
                                                    .font(.HelveticaNeueMedium(size: 32))
                                                    .foregroundColor(Asset.textForegroundColor.swiftUIColor)
                                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                                    .frame(width: reader.size.width-80)
                                                    .textContentType(.name)
                                                    .id(player.id)
                                                Spacer()
                                                    .frame(height: 27)
                                            }.padding(.trailing, 12)
                                            
                                        }
                                        Spacer().frame(height: 450)
                                    }
                                }
                                .onReceive(viewState.$focusItemId) { item in
                                    withAnimation {
                                        focusItemId = item
                                        value.scrollTo(item, anchor: .top)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.padding(.leading, 50)
                        }
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 80)
                    VStack  {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(spacing: 30) {
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                viewState.didTapAddPlayerButton()
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(L10n.Localizable.Players.Button.addPlayer)
                                        .font(.HelveticaNeueLight(size: 35))
                                        .foregroundColor(Asset.accentColor.swiftUIColor)
                                }
                            }.padding(.trailing, 20)
                            Button {
                                viewState.didTapToPlayButton()
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(L10n.Localizable.Players.Button.next)
                                        .font(.HelveticaNeueMedium(size: 44))
                                        .foregroundColor(Asset.accentColor.swiftUIColor)
                                }
                            }.padding(.trailing, 20)
                        }
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .background(Asset.mainColor.swiftUIColor)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Asset.mainColor.swiftUIColor)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                viewState.didAppear()
            }
        }
    }

In the app organizer, I see that:
libswiftCore.dylib Array.subscript.read

5 libswiftCore.dylib protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance [A]

6 SwiftUl closure #1 in Binding<A>.subscript.getter

7 SwiftUl FunctionalLocation.get()

8 SwiftUl LocationBox.get()

60 SwiftUl runApp<A>(_:)

61 SwiftUl static App.main ()

62 fivesecondbattle static RootApp.$main()

63 fivesecondbattle main

64 dyld start

Note message:
SwiftUI: closure #1 in Binding<A>.subscript.getter + 212

Detailed log:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c4aa3c8 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in assertionFailure(::file:line:flags:) + 228 (AssertCommon.swift:108)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c4aa2a0 closure #1 in closure #1 in assertionFailure(::file:line:flags:) + 332 (AssertCommon.swift:101)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c4a9c2c assertionFailure(::file:line:flags:) + 184 (AssertCommon.swift:97)
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c488494 Array.checkSubscript(:wasNativeTypeChecked:) + 156 (Array.swift:395)
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c48b810 Array.subscript.read + 180 (Array.swift:0)
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018c48b728 protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance [A] + 68 (:0)
6   SwiftUI                         0x000000019320a598 closure #1 in Binding.subscript.getter + 212 (Binding.swift:253)
7   SwiftUI                         0x0000000191c9b2e8 FunctionalLocation.get() + 28 (Location.swift:197)
8   SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
9   SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef2d8 protocol witness for Location.get() in conformance LocationBox + 24 (:0)
10  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef6a8 ProjectedLocation.get() + 228 (Location.swift:161)
11  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
12  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cf0acc Binding.ScopedLocation.get() + 56 (Binding.swift:389)
13  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
14  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cf0acc Binding.ScopedLocation.get() + 56 (Binding.swift:389)
15  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
16  SwiftUI                         0x000000019296f750 ZipLocation.get() + 72 (Location.swift:249)
17  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
18  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef2d8 protocol witness for Location.get() in conformance LocationBox + 24 (:0)
19  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef6a8 ProjectedLocation.get() + 228 (Location.swift:161)
20  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191cef4f0 LocationBox.get() + 216 (Location.swift:80)
21  SwiftUI                         0x00000001928a3708 specialized StateOrBinding.wrappedValue.getter + 776 (StateOrBinding.swift:37)
22  SwiftUI                         0x000000019289ba48 specialized TextField.state.modify + 192 (:0)
23  SwiftUI                         0x00000001928a01b0 closure #1 in PlatformTextFieldCoordinator.didBeginEditing() + 56 (SystemTextFieldStyle_PhoneTVWatch.swift:478)
24  SwiftUI                         0x00000001928a0e4c PlatformTextFieldCoordinator.textFieldDidBeginEditing(:) + 60
25  SwiftUI                         0x00000001928a0a18 @objc PlatformTextFieldCoordinator.textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:) + 52 (:0)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901c4e60 -[UITextField _notifyDidBeginEditing] + 104 (UITextField.m:1924)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901c3950 -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 196 (UITextField.m:1856)
28  UIKitCore                       0x000000019012e630 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 548 (UIResponder.m:407)
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001900d0ee4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 120 (UIView.m:13527)
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901c3d44 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 164 (UITextField.m:1491)
31  UIKitCore                       0x0000000190ed4e1c -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessaryActivatingSelection:] + 128 (UITextInteractionAssistant.m:1771)
32  UIKitCore                       0x0000000190eb848c -[UITextSelectionInteraction _checkForRepeatedTap:gestureLocationOut:] + 188 (UITextSelectionInteraction.m:324)
33  UIKitCore                       0x0000000190eb930c -[UITextSelectionInteraction _handleMultiTapGesture:] + 852 (UITextSelectionInteraction.m:639)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901c531c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100 (UIApplication.m:5616)
35  UIKitCore                       0x000000019081dee4 -[UITextMultiTapRecognizer onStateUpdate:] + 280 (UITextMultiTapRecognizer.m:62)
36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901f4e7c -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 128 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:157)
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901f4cec _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 92 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1639)
38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901f4aac _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 268 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1678)
39  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe869d0 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents] + 544 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:0)
40  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe5411c _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 2476 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:198)
41  UIKitCore                       0x000000018ff4fbc0 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 300 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:1378)
42  UIKitCore                       0x0000000190106680 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 188 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:1345)
43  UIKitCore                       0x0000000190105944 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3188 (UIWindow.m:3649)
44  UIKitCore                       0x000000018ff869e0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 564 (UIApplication.m:12721)
45  UIKitCore                       0x000000018ff881d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 5552 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2598)
46  UIKitCore                       0x000000018ff90ecc __processEventQueue + 5624 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2956)
47  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe8384c updateCycleEntry + 160 (UIEventDispatcher.m:126)
48  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe8176c _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84 (_UIUpdateSequence.mm:119)
49  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe813b0 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 172 (_UIUpdateScheduler.m:1058)
50  UIKitCore                       0x000000018fe82254 runloopSourceCallback + 92 (UIUpdateScheduler.m:1221)
51  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018db9f834 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
52  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018db9f7c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
53  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018db9d298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244 (CFRunLoop.c:2038)
54  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018db9c484 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2955)
55  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018db9bcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
56  GraphicsServices                0x00000001d2a4c1a8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
57  UIKitCore                       0x00000001901d490c -[UIApplication run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3713)
58  UIKitCore                       0x00000001902889d0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5303)
59  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191d8c148 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(:) + 168 (UIKitApp.swift:51)
60  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191d38714 runApp(:) + 152 (UIKitApp.swift:14)
61  SwiftUI                         0x0000000191d444d0 static App.main() + 132 (App.swift:114)
62  fivesecondbattle                0x0000000104d91750 static RootApp.$main() + 48 (RootApp.swift:0)
63  fivesecondbattle                0x0000000104d91750 main + 60
64  dyld                            0x00000001b124de4c start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1298)
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Note, you should not have @StateObject var viewState: PlayerViewState, use @StateObject var viewState = PlayerViewState()
or @ObservedObject var viewState: PlayerViewState.
Importantly, you should have ForEach($viewState.players) { $player in  ...}.
Try also using .onChange(of: focusItemId) instead of onReceive(...)

.onReceive is for publishers, for changes to lets or states just use body.

@malhal what's do you mean?)

@workingdogsupportUkraine viewState have init with View Init, it's working perfectly. Why I should use $player in foreach it's work without it and have a competition error with $. And I try change onRecive to onChange, but it's not explain the crash reason (

Don't use @StateObject var viewState: PlayerViewState.
It seems that ForEach($viewState.players) { player in ...} now works, don't know why.
Before I had to do ForEach($viewState.players) { $player in ...} and
TextField(..., text: $player.name).
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
There are too many parts missing, especially the overall context, how you pass and
declare your PlayerViewState and its players.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Hello!
Still try fix the bug.
It's a repository with reproducing bug -https://github.com/maukur/760410/tree/main.
But it's shows some times may be 1 of 100.
If you have any ideas it will be great =)

Your code is too long and convoluted to make sense to me. Note, in your RootApp, for example and elsewhere, you should not declare @ObservedObject var navigationService: NavigationService it should be @StateObject var navigationService: NavigationService to represent the single source of data truth.
And in the init(), it should be _ navigationService = StateObject(wrappedValue: .....) etc... Those classes should be also declared as class MyObject: ObservableObject { @Published var ...} and include @Published  var.
These @Published var, should not publish Views.

Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data (not Views) in your app.
